# getting http 415, Unsupported Media Type using text/xml

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, media-type, http-status-code-415

I have a jersey endpoint(JAX-RS) that I'm trying to hit with a text/xml req.  I'm getting back an http 415 and I don't understand why.  Here is the info.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

```
@Path("/bid")
@Produces("text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1")
@Consumes({"text/xml", "application/xml"})
@Resource
public class BidController {

@RolesAllowed("blah")
@POST
public Response bid(final HttpServletRequest request) {
```

I am hitting it via Postman(REST client) and sending {"Content-Type":"text/xml"}

My POST body is definitely well formed xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a 415 response because JAX-RS does not know how to convert incoming XML into a `HttpServletRequest`.

If you really want access to the request, then you need to annotate it with [@javax.ws.rs.core.Context](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html):

```
@RolesAllowed("blah")
@POST
public Response bid(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
```

However, as you say you're hitting it with `text/xml`, then you may actually want:

```
@POST
public Response bid(final MyRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

where `MyRequest` is declared something like:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyRequest {

     @XmlElement
     int field1;

     @XmlElement
     String field2;

     ...
}
```

which corresponds to XML like:

```
<MyRequest>
    <field1>11327</field1>
    <field2>some string
</MyRequest>
```

The JAX-RS specification requires implementations to be able to decode incoming text/xml and encode outgoing text/xml via JAXB.

Comment: Btw, isn't it Application/xml?